# Bounds on radius given positive second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, submanifold

Given a closed hypersurface $\Sigma^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If the second fundamental form $II\geq 1$, then does $\Sigma$ lies within a ball of radius 1?

Any references will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is surprisingly hard to prove, even for the case $n=2$. The approach I know uses the support function of a convex body and the fact that its Hessian is the inverse of the second fundamental form.

Comment: Could you please send me the link of the paper? Thanks!